# How do I notify listener which field of a struct is updated?

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

Actually, my question is related to language (I'm using C++).

I have a class

```
sturct StudentInfo
{
  // lots of fileds
  string id;
  string name;
  int age;
  double height;
  ......
};

class IListner
{
    void OnStudentInfoChanged(StudentInfo aLatestInfo);
};
void ListenStudnetInfoChange(IListener* aListener);
```

I want that if a user received the callback OnStudentInfoChanged

The receiver can distinguish which fields are being updated.

I don't know if there is an elegant pattern dealing with this problem.

My intuitive solution is to provide a 1-1 mapping enum

like

```
enum StudentInfoFields 
{
  field1,
  field2,
  .... 
};
```

and change

```
void OnStudentInfoChanged(StudentInfo aLatestInfo);
```

to

```
void OnStudentInfoChanged(vector<StudentInfoFields> aWhichAreChanged,
                          StudentInfo aLatestInfo);
```

It's not a good idea I think, but I don't have any idea to let a user know.

Please give me some suggestions :)

Thanks.

Comment: Why the `c#` tag?

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: Maybe because of revesve p-invoke

Comment: I support your idea of passing the name of modified fields along with the object.

Comment: An alternative is to pass old value and new value (`void OnStudentInfoChanged(const StudentInfo& old, const StudentInfo& current);`), and let caller checks which fields changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Observer pattern** looks like what you need, whose main idea is that each instance of the  `StudentInfo` should keep a list of observers and notify them when it's updated.

Comment: but the main problem is that, maybe I have 100 fields in the struct, when I callback the observer, I would like to tell the observer which fields are really being modified.

Comment: If you want to know which field is being updated, I don't have any other solutions easier than yours.